# Can $\pi$ be approximated by considering polygons with increasing number of sides, but without using circles or trigonometry?

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction, quadrilateral

Question in title. Although it should say “regular polygons”, not just “polygons”. When I say "without using circles", I mean without circle constructions.

Properties like perimeter and area and angles of other straight-edged quadrilaterals and triangles are allowed. Use of Pythagoras' Theorem is allowed.

For a polygon define "diameter" to be the longest straight line joining two corners of the regularpolygon. And define "radius" to be $\frac {diameter}{2}$.

So for example, with a regular hexagon,  we have 6 equilateral triangles. Using the fact that an equilateral triangle has 3 sides of equal length, 3 equal angles, and we also use Pythagoras, we get $\frac{perimeter \ length}{"diameter" \ length} = 3$.
We also get the area of the regular hexagon divided by the "radius"$ ^2 = \frac{3\sqrt3}{2} \approx 2.598.$

The aim is to approximate $\pi$ using only straight line geometry.

But I don't see how to do approximations to $\pi$ using regular polygons with more than 6 sides.

It's not obvious that it cannot be done either...

Comment: You start with a square inscribed in the unit circle (so area of circle is $\pi$), then double the sides. This is one of the canonical ways of approximating $\pi$.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how you approximate $\pi$ with an octagon. Please elaborate.

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem: to calculate the perimeter of the regular polygon without using trigonometric functions?

Comment: Not quite. Define the "diameter" of a polygon to be the longest straight line joining two corners of the polygon. My aim is to calculate either the ratio $\frac{perimeter 
 \ length}{diamteter } $ or the ratio $\frac{polygon \ area}{(diamteter/2)^2 } $ without alluding to circles or trigonometry . If you can do either approximation for polygons of increasing number of sides, then surely that is a method to approximate $\pi$ without alluding to circles or trigonometry (which itself requires circles).

Comment: The perimeter of a regular octagon of diameter $2$ is easy enough to write down, it is $8$ times the distance between the two adjacent vertices $(1,0)$ and $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$ which, without simplification, is $8 \sqrt{(1-\sqrt{2}/2)^2 + (0-\sqrt{2}/2)^2}$. For a regular octagon of diameter $d$, just multiply that expression by $d$.

Comment: But when you write "If we can do **this method**..." (my emphasis), I'm not sure what method you are referring to. You've left the concept of "this method" rather vague.

Comment: Ok, fair criticism. I've updated the original question to clarify that part. Let me know if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: From your new definition it does not follow that the polygon is regular, and if it is not regular, the ratio of the perimeter to diameter will not tend to $\pi$.

Comment: Ok I’ve updated the question again. I meant to be talking about only “regular polygons” throughout the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I was misremembering in my comment, I think the perimeter is easier to work with than the area. So you start with a circle of circumference $\pi$ (meaning a radius of $\frac{1}{2}$). Find the length of the side of the square (it will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$), so the initial guess is $4\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = 2\sqrt{2} \approx 2.828427$:

[image: Quarter Circle]

Here is a concrete example where we can use the previous known chord (in this case $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$) to find the next:

[image: Eighth Circle]

This gives $\pi \approx 3.0614674$. Now, here is the general case, where you know the previous chord, $s_n$, and then find the next (knowing that each time, you're bisecting the previous chord so the number of sides doubles). I think this formula is correct, the formula for $s_{n+1}$ given $s_n$ is definitely correct because I tested it, but not entirely certain about the perimeter formula:

[image: n-circle]

Using the above, we can write:

$$
s_{n+1}^2 = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - s_n^2}}{2}
$$

So we can find:

\begin{align*}
P_1 \approx &\ 2.8284271247461903\\
P_2 \approx &\ 3.061467458920718\\
P_3 \approx &\ 3.121445152258053\\
P_4 \approx &\ 3.1365484905459406\\
P_5 \approx &\ 3.140331156954739\\
P_6 \approx &\ 3.141277250932757\\
P_7 \approx &\ 3.1415138011441455\\
P_8 \approx &\ 3.1415729403678827\\
P_9 \approx &\ 3.141587725279961\\
P_{11} \approx &\ 3.141591421504635\\
P_{12} \approx &\ 3.141592345611077\\
P_{13} \approx &\ 3.1415925765450043\\
P_{14} \approx &\ 3.1415926334632482\\
P_{15} \approx &\ 3.141592654807589\\
P_{16} \approx &\ 3.1415926453212153\\
P_{17} \approx &\ 3.1415926073757197\\
P_{18} \approx &\ 3.1415929109396727\\
P_{19} \approx &\ 3.141594125195191\\
P_{20} \approx &\ 3.1415965537048196\\
P_{21} \approx &\ 3.1415965537048196
\end{align*}

This gives five digits of precision: $\pi \approx 3.14159$.

This example was taught to me in my Scientific Computing class *way* back to display roundoff error in floating point calculations. You'll notice on the last two, we get the same result. That's because the floating point calculations of the computer have essentially hit their limit. The reason for this is because $s_n^2$ has become so small, that $1 - s_n^2$ doesn't generate a "new" number (it just keeps giving the same number that will generate $s_n^2$ again when subtracted from $1$. There is a trick to make this calculation better:

\begin{align*}
s_{n+1}^2 =&\ \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - s_n^2}}{2}\cdot\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - s_n^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - s_n^2}} \\
=&\ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1 - \left(1 - s_n^2\right)}{1 + \sqrt{1 - s_n^2}}\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{s_n^2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - s_n^2}}
\end{align*}

This really does give better results:

\begin{align*}
P_1 \approx&\ 2.8284271247461903 \\
P_2 \approx&\ 3.0614674589207183\\
P_3 \approx&\ 3.1214451522580524\\
P_4 \approx&\ 3.1365484905459393\\
P_5 \approx&\ 3.140331156954753\\
P_6 \approx&\ 3.141277250932773\\
P_7 \approx&\ 3.1415138011443013\\
P_8 \approx&\ 3.1415729403670913\\
P_9 \approx&\ 3.1415877252771596\\
P_{10} \approx&\ 3.1415914215111997\\
P_{11} \approx&\  3.1415923455701176\\
P_{12} \approx&\  3.1415925765848725\\
P_{13} \approx&\  3.1415926343385627\\
P_{14} \approx&\  3.1415926487769856\\
P_{15} \approx&\  3.141592652386591\\
P_{16} \approx&\   3.141592653288993\\
P_{17} \approx&\  3.141592653514593\\
P_{18} \approx&\  3.141592653570993\\
P_{19} \approx&\  3.1415926535850933\\
P_{20} \approx&\  3.141592653588618\\
P_{21} \approx&\  3.1415926535894996\\
P_{22} \approx&\  3.1415926535897203\\
P_{23} \approx&\  3.1415926535897754\\
P_{24} \approx&\  3.141592653589789\\
P_{25} \approx&\  3.1415926535897927\\
P_{26} \approx&\  3.1415926535897936\\
P_{27} \approx&\  3.1415926535897936\\
\end{align*}

By simply changing the computation, *not the algorithm!*, we now get *twelve* digits of precision! $\pi \approx 3.141592653589$--all because of floating point roundoff error.

Comment: I’ll go over this in detail tomorrow, but it looks like the sort of thing I’m after. Maybe I should have done a drawing like you did in my question, but it takes me ages to do that with punt. Out of interest, what program do you use for those drawings?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Probably not a good one, but it's called [IPE](http://ipe.otfried.org/). I used it because it was recommended to me by a professor, but mainly, it supports Latex.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can do this "without trigonometry" depends in a way on your definition of trigonometry.

Archimedes repeatedly bisected the sides of inscribed polygons. To do that he used what are now known as the double angle formulas from trigonometry, but he proved them using Euclidean geometric tools.

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m446-03/pi.pdf

Comment: My understanding is Archimedes gave a closed neighborhood bracketing $\pi$, to wit $3+(10/71)<\pi<3+(1/7)$.  He would have had to double sides of circumscribed polygons too.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, with the same double angle formulas.